# Automated Chromedriver PDF Download Brings Up Button?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium to download an embedded pdf accessed through many complex layers of logins and other browser actions. I've set up my chromedriver with the following options per instruction from various other posts:

```
    chromedriver = r'C:\Users\cj9250\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\chromedriver.exe'
    download_dir = "C:\\Users\\CJ9250\\Downloads\\" # for linux/*nix, download_dir="/usr/Public"

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    profile = {
            "plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}], 
           "download.default_directory": download_dir , 
           "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf",
           "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
           "download.prompt_for_download": False,
           "safebrowsing.enabled": True
           }
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options=options)
```

However, I get this box that I have to click before it downloads to my specified directory:

[image]

The 'Open' element doesn't have an xpath that I can find through the inspector. I'm guessing that this is some kind of internal security setting for the ChromeDriver but I can't find a way past it.

My end goal is just to download a embedded PDF in an open Selenium Test page, this seemed the only suggested course of action.

reportSho.do OPEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it worked but, I modified my profile variable to:

```
profile = {
            "plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}], # Disable Chrome's PDF Viewer
           "download.default_directory": download_dir , 
           "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf",
           "safebrowsing.enabled": False
           }
```

From there I was able to get a frame element on the page with the open button. One of the element attributes had a URL. When I instructed the browser to go to the URL, it downloaded the file to my specified directory!

[image]